# Strange behavior of bitmap position

Tags: java, android, animation, bitmap, position

I have a line drawn at the bottom of the screen at Y position 1072, which is 1 inch from the bottom of the screen (screenHeight - dpi). I am trying to make bitmap objects disappear when they pass the line:

```
for (int i=0;i<objectList.size();i++) {
    if (objectList.get(i).y >= (screenHeight-dpi) - objectList.get(i).objectBitmap.getHeight()) {
        Log.d("Line Collison", "Working");
    }
}
```

I tested it by logging several variables:

- Bitmap's Y position (logged every frame)
- Line's position: 1072
- Line    position minus bitmap height (objects should disappear after
  passing): 944

I stopped the application when an object reached the line, and observed that its logged Y position was only 475, which is about half of the point at which it's supposed to disappear (944). The bitmap I'm using is 128 pixels in height and doesn't have top/bottom padding. So what could be the problem here?

Comment: You need to provide more information about logic of hiding the bitmap. Basically right now there is no mistake.

Comment: @VladimirLichonos Hiding the bitmap isn't the problem. You'll notice in the if statement used to detect whether an object has crossed the line, I replaced the method for hiding the object with a log, the value of which I never see as it does not work properly.

Comment: can you explain `(screenHeight-dpi)`,  might help to understand more?

Comment: @petey The screen height minus the DPI is one inch above the bottom of the screen...

Comment: sounds right, what of "observed that it's logged Y position was only 475"...can you post this part of the code base?

Comment: @petey Not exactly sure what you want me to post - I log the bitmap's Y position at the end of every frame. I started the application, then stopped it when I saw that the bitmap had touched the line and observed the last Y position logged, which was 475, although the bitmap appeared to be just below the line at 1072.

Comment: yea. I'd love to see the part where you capture and log the Y position.

Comment: @petey I figured it out. Didn't have anything to do with the logging of the Y ;) All of my code was correct, a part was just misplaced

Comment: @ZachH  ahh nice.. gratz man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My method was placed within the wrong set of braces.**

[image: Facepalm.]